# Reading multiple values in C using scanf

Tags: c

There is another thread explaining the way to get multiple values using scanf(). I tried that, however, I got correct value for the first variable and junk values for the remaining two variables. When I used separate scanf statements, it worked fine.
I am using RH Linux 5.
Kernel version - 2.6.18-238. 4.1.2

e.g. if I do `scanf("%d %d %d",&n,&p1,&p2)`, then n is read fine. But p1 is assigned 32767 and p2 is assigned another number even after I read the values. But according to the thread on SO, it should work. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How are you introducing the numbers? If you separate them by return, they won't be read well. You have to provide all three separated by spaces.

Comment: `scanf` returns the number of succesfully read items. If it doesn't return 3 in your example, then something went wrong trying to read the values.

Comment: please post a piece of code that shows the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what types the three variables are. They have to be `int`.

The following code works as expected on my computer:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, p1, p2;
  scanf("%d %d %d", &n, &p1, &p2);
  printf("%d %d %d\n", n, p1, p2);
  return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
$ gcc x.c
$ ./a.out 
10 3 5
10 3 5
```